# Finding Volumes of Solids Revolved Around Lines, Not Axes

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm attempting to find the volume of a solid in Mathematica when it is revolved around a line that isn't the axis. I'm revolving what I get within the x > 0 region of these two curves, f(x) and g(x).

I believe I got this working with the y-axis:

```
f[x_] := 3x^3 - 0.75x^5
g[x_] := x^2 - 6x + 2
{x1, x2}=x/. Solve[f[x]==g[x] && x > 0,x, Reals];
vol1=2 Pi NIntegrate[x (f[x] - g[x]), {x, x1, x2}]
```

**I do NOT need a graph**, just a volume. It seems all of the tutorials I have found online are more about graphs and less about finding just the numerical volume of these solids. I could care less about a RegionPlot or anything of the like...I just need a numerical quantity.

Here's the issue...I would like to use lines that aren't the axis now. I can't seem to find any good way to set this up in Mathematica; given the nature of the calculations here, there's a good reason I'm not doing this by hand.

If I wanted to revolve around x = 8, would this be as simple as adjusting something in my boundaries or is there something more?

What if I wanted to use a horizontal line that isn't the x-axis...say, y = -10?

I can't find anything in Mathematica's documentation on this. I'm sure there's some way to do it in here. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2914182).

Comment: No it's not. That is a DIFFERENT post by me.

Comment: Any lines, or only lines parallel to one or another axis?

Answer (score 2):

### Method-1 : `ImplicitRegion`.

We rotate around `x==8`, that is around the point `{8,0}` in the x-y plane.

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[{x1 <= 8 - Sqrt[(x - 8)^2 + (y - 0)^2] <= x2, 
    0 <= z <= 
     f[8 - Sqrt[(x - 8)^2 + (y - 0)^2]] - 
      g[8 - Sqrt[(x - 8)^2 + (y - 0)^2]]}, {x, y, z}];
reg // Volume
```

> `424.783`.

### Method-2 `ParametricRegion`.

We `RotationTransform` the curve `{x,0,f[x]-g[x]}` around the line with the direction `dir={0,0,1},{0,0,1},{1,0,0}` which through the point `pt={0,0,0},{8, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -10}` respectivly.

```
{ParametricPlot3D[
  RotationTransform[θ, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}]@{x, 0, 
    f[x] - g[x]}, {x, x1, x2}, {θ, 0, 2 π}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  RotationTransform[θ, {0, 0, 1}, {8, 0, 0}]@{x, 0, 
    f[x] - g[x]}, {x, x1, x2}, {θ, 0, 2 π}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  RotationTransform[θ, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -10}]@{x, 0, 
    f[x] - g[x]}, {x, x1, x2}, {θ, 0, 2 π}]}
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x, 0, h}, {x, x1, x2}, {h, 0, f[x] - g[x]}, 
 PlotPoints -> 60, MaxRecursion -> 4]
regs = {ParametricRegion[
    RotationTransform[θ, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}]@{x, 0, h}, {{x, 
      x1, x2}, {h, 0, f[x] - g[x]}, {θ, 0, 2 π}}], 
   ParametricRegion[
    RotationTransform[θ, {0, 0, 1}, {8, 0, 0}]@{x, 0, h}, {{x, 
      x1, x2}, {h, 0, f[x] - g[x]}, {θ, 0, 2 π}}], 
   ParametricRegion[
    RotationTransform[θ, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -10}]@{x, 0, 
      h}, {{x, x1, x2}, {h, 0, f[x] - g[x]}, {θ, 0, 2 π}}]};
regs // Volume
```

[image]

> `{93.2235, 424.783, 881.322}`

Answer (score 1):

To rotate some area around an arbitrary line we may give an example. We need to make some assumptions. Given 2 curves f[x] and g[x] that intersect at 2 points: xa,xb. We want to rotate the area between f and g around some arbitrary line: line[x].

Note, for an example I am going to scale the y axis of your example by 1/10. This will make the plots better to understand.

First we define the functions, their intersections and an arbitrary line with offset: y0 and an angle: ang relative to the x axis:

```
f[x_] := 0.1 (3 x^3 - 0.75 x^5)
g[x_] := 0.1 (x^2 - 6 x + 2)
{xa, xb} = x /. Solve[f[x] == g[x] && x > 0, x, Reals];
line[x_] = 0.4 + 0.4 x; y0 = line[0]; ang = ArcTan[1, line'[0]];
```

Next we define a transformation that shifts the y axis by y0 and then rotates around the origin by -ang. By this the transformed line will be on the x axis:

```
trans[x_, y_] = RotationMatrix[-ang] . {x, y - y0};
```

Next we can define the transformed functions, line and intersection points:

```
f1[x_] = trans[x, f[x]][[2]];
g1[x_] = trans[x, g[x]][[2]];
line1[x_] = trans[x, line[x]][[2]];
xa1 = trans[xa, f[xa]][[1]];
xb1 = trans[xb, f[xb]][[1]];
```

The volume of the rotation body is now the integral:

```
Integrate[f1[x] - g1[x], {x, xa1, xb1}]

0.618665
```

To visualize the transformation, we may plot of the original functions and line:

```
Plot[{f[x], g[x], line[x]}, {x, 0, 2.5}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {-2, 1}]
```

[image]

and the transformed functions and line:

```
Plot[{f1[x], g1[x], line1[x], f1[x]}, {x, 0, 2.5}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {-2, 1}]
```

[image]

Note that line1 is on the x axis.

Answer (score 1):

Let `reg` be the region to be revolved about a line `x == c`.
Then

```
volume = Integrate[2 * Pi * RealAbs[x-c], Element[{x, y}, reg]]
```

Revolved about a line `y == c`:

```
volume = Integrate[2 * Pi * RealAbs[y-c], Element[{x, y}, reg]]
```

Example:

```
reg = Triangle[{{1, 2}, {4, 1}, {3, 3}}];

Integrate[2*Pi*RealAbs[y - c], Element[{x, y}, reg]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Integrate[2*Pi*RealAbs[y - 10], Element[{x, y}, reg]]
```

> ```
> 40 \[Pi]
> ```

One can generalize to oblique lines:

```
Integrate[
 2*Pi*RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[p, v], {x, y}], 
 Element[{x, y}, reg]]
```

Triangle example:

```
Integrate[
 2*Pi*RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[{0, 2}, {1, 2}], {x, y}], 
 Element[{x, y}, reg]]
```

> ```
> (*  (16 Sqrt[5] \[Pi])/3  *)
> ```

Comment: Note: The results for $1<c<3$ should be incorrect, since the integral should count the overlapping volume twice. But traditionally one doesn't ask for the volume for a line passing through the region.